# Exception occur while adding external jars in android app

Tags: java, android, jaxb

I'm facing this problem since 3 days
I'm developing an android app which uses soap web services
When I use this jar `ws-combine-jar` or any other jar such as j`axb-api` or `javax.jws` and when i try to run the app, i get this error in `gradle console` :

```
> trouble processing "javax/xml/bind/Binder.class": Ill-advised or
> mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when not building a
> core library. This is often due to inadvertently including a core
> library file in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
> Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a core
> class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's going on.
> However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
> namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example, from a
> non-Android virtual machine project. This will most assuredly not
> work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the compatibility of your app with
> future versions of the platform. It is also often of questionable
> legality. If you really intend to build a core library -- which is
> only appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
> distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use the
> "--core-library" option to suppress this error message. If you go
> ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact building an
> application, then be forewarned that your application will still fail
> to build or run, at some point. Please be prepared for angry customers
> who find, for example, that your application ceases to function once
> they upgrade their operating system. You will be to blame for this
> problem. If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in
> a core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
> repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into your
> own package namespace. This means that they will never be in conflict
> with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help you in this
> endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then that is an
> indication that the path you are on will ultimately lead to pain,
> suffering, grief, and lamentation. 1 error; aborting  FAILED FAILURE:
> Build failed with an exception.
> * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\bin\java.exe'' finished with
> non-zero exit value 1
> * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. BUILD FAILED
```

I don't know how to solve, i tried enabling `multiDex`, clean and rebuild but it didn't work, please i need help.